# ROS and Python versions when launching nodes

Tags: python, ros

[ros_imu_bno055](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_imu_bno055) package works on Noetic running Ubuntu 20.04 (Intel NUC) but throws an error on Kinetic running on 16.04 (Raspberry Pi 3, Ubiquity Robotics image) must be python 3 vs 2?  Python3 on the NUC, python2 on the Pi. Kinda stuck not sure where to geek from here:-/

> process[ros_imu_bno055_node-1]: started with pid [4463]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/ros_imu_bno055/src/imu_ros.py", line 41, in <module>

    import rospy

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>

    from .client import spin, myargv, init_node, \

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 52, in <module>

    import roslib

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>

    from roslib.launcher import load_manifest

  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 42, in <module>

    import rospkg

ImportError: No module named 'rospkg'

[ros_imu_bno055_node-1] process has died [pid 4463, exit code 1, cmd /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/ros_imu_bno055/src/imu_ros.py __name:=ros_imu_bno055_node __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/53378000-5ab6-11ec-a639-b827ebceb04e/ros_imu_bno055_node-1.log].

log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/53378000-5ab6-11ec-a639-b827ebceb04e/ros_imu_bno055_node-1*.log

all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit

shutting down processing monitor...

... shutting down processing monitor complete

done
```

Answer (score 1):

It requires Python3, according to the [link you gave](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_imu_bno055#Requisites). Reqs copied here:

```
2. Requisites
1. Ubuntu with ROS
2. Python 3
3. Bosch IMU BNO055
4. USB Serial Converter
```

Comment: To add further context: The docs "say" there is a Kinetic release, however, it doesn't appear to be contained anywhere in the source repo; only Noetic. If written for Noetic you have no choice but to use Python3 unless you want to rewrite the source.